# Include image as a part of text file?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Is it possible to add image( signature captured from client on windows Mobile 6.5 device and saved as a file with jpeg extension) 
to text file using vb.net/C#?

objective: 
We were trying to include the signature of client from jpeg file to just below  Received By section of a text file

===================================
          Hotel XYZ
      No.26 abc road ....

## ***********************************

xyzsdafdsaf
Tokyo 28
Japan 55555555
Date    : 10/27/2014

---

Received by

[SignatureImage.jpg]

Comment: HTML? What happens to this text?

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for, but an ascii art generator like http://picascii.com/ is the closest you can get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to put anything but text in a text file.  If you want it to be visibly formatted as both text and an image, you will need to output it in a file format which supports both text and images.  For instance, you could use PDF or RTF.